# What is it the best solution to hide a single page application private pages with Firebase?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm going to explain the problem better with an example, in this Firebase official example https://office-mover-demo.firebaseapp.com/ I can show the hidden page without login with a simple command in the console:

```
 app.classList.remove('is-hidden');
```

Yes, of course, the data in firebase can be accessed only if a user successful logged in. So my question is: Can i do something to show the structure of the html private part only after a successful login of the user? (Only with static content and firebase auth)

Answer (score 2):

From the [Firebase documentation on monitoring authentication state](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-monitoring-authentication):

```
// Create a callback which logs the current auth state
function authDataCallback(authData) {
  if (authData) {
    console.log("User " + authData.uid + " is logged in with " + authData.provider);
  } else {
    console.log("User is logged out");
  }
}
// Register the callback to be fired every time auth state changes
var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");
ref.onAuth(authDataCallback);
```

Where the snippet calls `console.log`, you can just as easily show/hide the HTML.

Comment: Yeah i know, i'm talking about make the content of the div hidden private, unlocked only when the auth process is positive !

Comment: If that is not the same as showing/hiding the element in the `if (authData)` above, then I have no "private" and "unlocked" mean. You'll have to be clearer, preferably by including an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question.

Comment: The question is clear, hidden means not visible on the screen only, private means that the DOM is not accessible neither in the inspection with DevTool ( eg that part of DOM private is built only when the Auth is done).

Comment: There is no such thing as a private DOM, everything that is downloaded to the user's browser is discoverable by the user in some way. You can indeed load or construct DOM fragments on demand. Similarly to showing/hiding elements, you'd download/construct them in the relevant branch of the `if (authData)` above.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this problem - as I understand it - is to set a cookie upon user login containing the user's id or, with an additional call to Firebase, a secret visible only to the logged in client. My server can then read the cookie and determine whether the user is authorized to view the content and only then download it. Thus, I am using Firebase for authentication, but my own server for authorization.

It works, and I can also log the user in to my server using this approach just as if I had received an Oauth token.

However, lacking experience with cookies, I would like to know how secure this is!

Comment: Thanks, i know that this solution can work very well, but i'm looking for a smart solution with no back-end involved other than firebase. Thanks